# React SSR document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-ssr

I'm nearly done updating an old React (v15.2x) with SSR (RRv2.3) and webpack 1x code base for a movie app. I've updated nearly everything to current stuff (except for RRv3.2x).

I'm getting this error

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store.subscribe` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Provider
/home/david/tutorials/react/mgbp/mgbp-default-refactored/build/bundle.js:845
), document.getElementById('app'));
   ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

and its from this code

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={getRoutes(store)}/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```